# How using htaccess on Apache with mod_headers.c to send a http header with x-robots tag noindex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers

I have a list of 1000 URLs with IDs in this form:
hotel/waikiki-beach;HNL41184 
and ";HNL41184" is the ID ";" is the separator.

Now I try to send a http header with a x-robots tag directive:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<Files ~ "\;HNL41174$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, follow"
</Files>
```

Is this correct? Or is there a better way to reach the traget?

Comment: Well if it works, it is correct. Have you checked that?

Comment: With my solution I don't see the x-robots in the http header. Is Files the wrong way?